# Why doesn't a limit exist when both the numerator and denominator don't approach 0?

Tags: calculus, limits

For example, $\lim\limits_{x\to5}\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-5}$ does not exist because $\lim\limits_{x \to 5} x^2-5x+6=6$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 5} x-5=0$.

Comment: The values of the fraction get arbitrarily large in absolute value, as opposed to getting close to a single real number, they get away from all real numbers. On the other hand, it is a very special way of non-existing. In some contexts this way of not existing is considered as good as existing.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Well, many textbooks don't consider that the limit "exists" in that case

Comment: SImply by the definition of lim?

Comment: There's a disconnect between the title and the actual question...

Comment: @goblin There isn't.

Comment: @Marja There is. "both ... don't" means that neither of them approach zero. It should be "... don't both", which means that at most one of them does.

Comment: @Daniel You're right. In this case limit simply doesn't exist. I initially miscomputed :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit in that case is $\infty$ from the right, and $-\infty$ from the left. The intuition is that as you divide a "fixed" positive number by smaller and smaller quantities, the result grows large unboundedly.

In the other hand, if both the numerator and denominator approach $0$ the same argument doesn't work. In fact, you will find examples where both the numerator and denominator approach $0$ and the limit can either exist and be equal to any number (including $0$), or the limit can equal $\pm\infty$, or it may not exist. That's why we say that $0/0$ is an indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example than yours is $\lim\limits_{x\to5}\frac{6}{x-5}$
and one even simpler is $\lim\limits_{x\to5}\frac{1}{x-5}$. One still even simpler is $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$.

Whatever $\delta>0$ you may choose, $\exists K>0$ such that $\forall x $ with $0<\lvert x\rvert<\delta$, it results $\left\lvert\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert>K$. Indeed it is sufficient to choose $K>\frac{1}{\delta}$

Answer (score 1):

When one takes the limit as $x\to 5+$ the ratio tends to $\infty$ whereas taking limit as $x \to 5-$ the ratio goes to $-\infty$ here in this particular example. Therefore the limit does not exists for this example.

Comment: How do you show that algebraically?

Comment: @sepehr78 Hint: Let $u=x-5$. Substituting gives $\lim\limits_{u\to0}u+5+6/u$, and clearly $1/u$ diverges to $-\inf$ approaching from the left and to $\inf$ approaching from the right.

Comment: The algebra can also be done by epsilon-delta argument. In this case we can show that in $\delta$ neighbourhood of $5$ the ratio can be made grater the $M$ for any $M>0$. The $\delta$ depends on $M$ and also the ratio can be made less than $-M$ by using Archimedean property.

Answer (score 0):

Overarching statement on limits:

When both the numerator $f(x)$ and denominator $g(x)$ of a rational function $r(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ approach $0$ as $x$ approaches some point $a$, the limit of $r$ is said to be of the indeterminate form of type $0/0$.

Here however, your limit is $+\infty$, the statemetn above however, is used for those limits that are indeterminate, which I think you were alluding to in your opening sentence.